# ASP.NET Resources (resx) doesn't work after migration to .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

a installed Visual Studio 2012 and migrate my Web Apps to .NET 4.5.
I had many resx files in App_GlobalResources and always it works.

After migration resx files generates in designer "**namespace MyApp.App_GlobalResources**"
instead of "namespace Resources".

I solved this with rename App_GlobalResources to "**Resources**" and change custom tool from "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator" to "**PublicResXFileCodeGenerator**".

But it doesn't work with expression e.g.: **<%$ Resources: Users, LoginTitle %>**

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I changed Custom Tool to : PublicResXFileCodeGenerator, I dont know if it worked for me.

The main issue is - In my case, when I built my MVC 3 project on Visual Studio 2012, it made namespace "Resources" for the .resx files.

As in Visual Studio 2010, it was under namespace "App_GlobalResources".

I renamed the namespace under designer.cs for the Resource files back to "App_GlobalResources", and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/15/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx). Now it works

I've set custom tool to : PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

custom tool namespace to: Resources

and build action: Embeded Resource

Comment: But then resource expressions like `<%$ Resources: Users, LoginTitle %>` won't work, anymore.